# AngularJS angular-modal-service giving me an error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to use AngularModalService.  Doing a copy/paste job from the admittedly simple tutorial gives me an error.

This is the tutorial, for reference:
http://www.dwmkerr.com/the-only-angularjs-modal-service-youll-ever-need/

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularModalService']);

app.controller( 'Controller', function($scope,ModalService) {

    $scope.show = function() {
        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: 'modal.html',
            controller: "ModalController"
        }).then(function(modal) {
            modal.element.modal(); // this is the problem
            modal.close.then(function(result) {
                $scope.message = "You said " + result;
            });
        });
    };
});

app.controller('ModalController', function( $scope, close ) {
    $scope.close = function(result) {
        close(result, 500);
    };
});

</script>
```

HTML (uglier in the tutorial, but should be simpler)

```
<div class="container" style="min-width: 700px; max-width: 700px; margin: 50px auto;" data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="Controller">
    <h3>Angular Modal Service</h3>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href ng-click="show()">Show a Modal</a>
    <p>{{message}}</p>

    <!-- The html template -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
        <div class="modal fade">
            <button type="button" ng-click="close('Cancel')" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Yes or No?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>It is your call...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" ng-click="close('No')" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="close('Yes')" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
        </div>
    </script>

</div>
```

The error I get is "undefined is not a function" on the line denoted above, which is:

```
modal.element.modal();
```

Google search has lead me to nothing concrete.  Hopefully I'm just overlooking something silly.

Comment: The tutorial is using Angular 1.2.9. What version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`angularModalService` requires `bootstrap js`. Call the following file in your `index.html` file and try.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That got me somewhere, sort of.  I found I also needed the boostrap.css file included as well as jquery (which was not there in the first place.).  Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes, you are welcome. one more thing, why are you not try angular bootstrap directives for dialog..

Comment: B/c I'm relatively new to Angular.  My front end coding skills are almost always on the desktop.  So, the code isn't too hard for me, but I'm unfamiliar with many of the concepts.  I have a working modal dialog right now, but it only supports basically open/close.  Wouldn't work well for something like login. When I google searched, almost everything led to AngularModalService. You an see what I have working (on an older version of Angular) here. http://onfilm.us/image_index.html.  For that one, I'd generally want to close w/ the X, but if a user clicks the tags, it should do something else.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because you are calling the Bootstrap method to show the modal.

Contrary to Asik's answer above, AngularModalService does *not* require Bootstrap, but if you are using Bootstrap modals then you do need to include the bootstrap js file.

The issue is referenced here: https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service/issues/14

Custom modals, not requiring Bootstrap, are shown in the [examples page](http://dwmkerr.github.io/angular-modal-service/#custom)

Comment: Cheers -- I will look into this as well. ;)